# aggregating means in a repeating structure in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have a dataframe like:

```
p <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

and I want the mean of every two consecutive values:

1+2/2 , 3+4/2 etc.

what I tried is:

```
agg_data <- aggregate(p, by= list(rep(1:2,5)), FUN= mean)
```

but the result is not what I want. It gives me the mean of every second value:

1+3+5+7+9/5 = 5

2+4+6+8+10/5 = 6

how can I change the function to get the right result?

Comment: I think you need `aggregate(p, by= list(rep(1:5,each = 2)), FUN= mean)`

Comment: thanks! it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `by` statement, change the `rep`

```
aggregate(p, by= list(rep(1:5,each = 2)), FUN= mean)
```